# Android item group android:checkableBehavior="single"

Tags: android, user-interface, menuitem

I want to programmatically set the radio button of a group according to some changing program status.

The XML file is like this:

```
<item android:id="@+id/silent_mode" android:title="@string/silent_mode" >
    <menu>
        <group android:checkableBehavior="single" android:id="@+id/silent_on_off">
            <item android:id="@+id/silent_mode_on"
                android:checked="false"
                android:title="@string/silent_mode_on_text"
                />
            <item android:id="@+id/silent_mode_off"
                android:checked="true"
                android:title="@string/silent_mode_off_text" />
        </group>
    </menu>
</item>
```

And then i wish to update the slient_mode_on or slient_mode_off according to some state of a variable, let say the boolean variable called isSilentMode.
The isSlientMode is a variable that change on the fly. There is a background service that check every 5 minutes. If the isSlientMode turn to true, then i want to set the slient_mode_on.setSelected(true), else set it to false.

I tried to set the MenuItem, but there is no response at all. The item keep to be at the same state as user previous selection, and will not update according to some program change.

How to handle this?

```
    public static void updateSilentModeCheckbox() {

    if (mainMenu!=null) {

        MenuItem itemOn = mainMenu.findItem(R.id.silent_mode_on);
        MenuItem itemOff = mainMenu.findItem(R.id.silent_mode_off);

        Log.i("MainActivity", itemOn.isChecked() + " " + isSilentMode + " ");
        if (itemOn.isChecked() && isSilentMode) {
            // silentModeOn, itemOnChecked, doNothing
        } else if (itemOn.isChecked() && !isSilentMode) {
            itemOff.setChecked(true);
            itemOn.setChecked(false);
        } else if (!itemOn.isChecked() && isSilentMode) {
            itemOn.setChecked(true);
            itemOff.setChecked(false);
        } else if (!itemOn.isChecked() && isSilentMode) {
            // doNothing
        }
        Log.i("MainActivity", itemOn.isChecked() + " " + isSilentMode + " ");
    }
}
```

I found that the status of the itemOn and itemOff never get updated.